# получать два случайных числа и чтобы одно число делилось на второе и возвращало целое число

Tags: javascript

Нужно получать два случайных числа и чтобы одно число делилось на второе и возвращало целое число

Comment: все просто: 1) получаем случайное число 2) умножаем первое число на случайное целое — второе случайное число

Answer (score 3):

Получите два случайных a, b и верните a, a*b

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Sergo Grikurov Если решение помогло, его можно принять как ответ

Answer (score 1):

Ну насколько я понимаю быть абсолютно случайными оба числа не могут, а значит случайным может быть только первое и на основе этого числа надо сгенерировать второе число:

```js
const getRandomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 101); 

// +1 чтобы не было деления на 0
const firstRandomNumber = getRandomNumber() + 1;
const secondRandomNumber = firstRandomNumber * getRandomNumber();

console.log(firstRandomNumber, secondRandomNumber);
console.log(secondRandomNumber / firstRandomNumber);
```